# Visual Studio Code does not find references of Angular variables in templates

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an `Angular 6` app, and using `VSCode 1.31.1` on Windows 7 with `Angular Language Service 0.1.11`.

When I right-click a method name and select **"Find all references"**, references from templates do not show up.

This makes refactoring harder : when renaming a field/method, one can easily miss calls to this field/method from either html files or inlined templates.

Is there a setting or an extension that can help ?

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: No, sorry. And since I switched to a legacy project I didn't take the time to find one.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/29) for that, which is now [implemented](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/29#issuecomment-765598694).

> This has been fixed by the new Ivy-native language service, released
> in [v11.1.0](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/releases/tag/v11.1.0). It's an opt-in feature for now, please give it a try and
> let us know if you have any feedback. For the best editor experience,
> please make sure your project has [`strictTemplates`](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#stricttemplates) enabled in
> `angularCompilerOptions`. In case you run into similar bug, please file
> a new issue. I'll close this for now.

Answer (score 1):

If I open an Angular project in VS Code and use the `Find All References` command w/o starting the application first, the references are *not* found in the HTML templates.  However, if I build the project (`npm start` / `ng start`), then the HTML template references *are* found.

My environment:

- Angular 6.14.15
- Windows 10
- VS Code 1.68.1

Answer (score 0):

I have a few extensions installed and they are great!, IDK witch one gives you the reference functionality.
Search for:

1. Angular Language service
2. Angular 7 snippets
3. Angular Schematics

Comment: Reference functionality seems to be provided by Angular Language Service. It works well for me with references from TypeScript code, but not from templates.

Comment: I found this one too, try it. It works for me with the template references: Angular Follow Selector. The link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sanderledegen.angular-follow-selector

Comment: Thank you Jon, this extension is useful, although it does not answer my problem.